# Plot a peak with height

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

How can I properly plot a peak in Matlab with a given height? My current method:

```
x = linspace(0,500,500);
peaks = zeros(size(x));
peaks(50) = 5;
peaks(300) = 20;
peaks(302) = 17;
peaks(375) = 15;
plot(x,peaks)
```

which gives

[image: Peaks]

But this is ugly, confusing when multiple lines are close and leads to problems when converting it to a log scale since `log(0)=-Inf`. Is there a proper way of plotting peaks?

---

Context: I'm trying to analyse a spectogram (EDXS) to identify which material I'm working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling the scale to log, you are asking Matlab to draw a line between -Inf and a positive value. Such lines are skipped.

To get a usable log plot, use points instead of lines:

```
plot(x,peaks,'x')
```

Another nice possibility to plot peaks is a `stem`-plot

[image]

Comment: The function `stem` was the answer I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why you only get single pixels in your log-plot is because most of your values are `0`. As `log(0) = -Inf`, this can't be plotted.

I know nothing of spectogram analyses, but if you absolutely want to plot this with a logarithmic scale, is it possible to use a "base line" equal 1 (0 in a log scale). If so:

```
x = linspace(0,100);
peaks = ones(size(x));
peaks(10) = 5;
peaks(60) = 20;
peaks(75) = 15; 
semilogy(x,peaks)
```

[image]

I guess that this will look more reasonable with your real data. Note: If you have values that are less than `1`, I would not go with this approach!

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not explain the problem properly enough, I've updated my question. There are more problems than just the log-scale. I'm really searching for a proper way of plotting peaks. Thanks for taking the time though.